# SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 (Laravel create new row with eloquent)

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

In Laravel I have a controller that take a request from ajax, and insert data in a DB table, the following code works good

-Laravel controller function

```
public function updateFormcoords(Request $data, Form $form)
{
    if ($data->ajax()){
        $formcoord=new Formcoord;
        $formcoord->field_name=$data->input('field_name');          
        $formcoord->x=$data->input('x');
        $formcoord->y=$data->input('y');
        $formcoord->w=$data->input('w');   
        $formcoord->h=$data->input('h');
        $formcoord->r=$data->input('r');
        $formcoord->shape=$data->input('shape');
        $formcoord->fill=$data->input('fill'); 
        $formcoord->q_id=$data->input('q_id');
        $formcoord->q_option=$data->input('q_option');*/
        $form->formcoords()->save($formcoord); 
    }
}
```

-the ajax request is the following:

```
        $.ajax({
            async: false,
            url: {{ route(updateFormcoords) }},
            headers: {"X-CSRF-TOKEN": token},
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {field_name:boxes[i].field_name, x: x, y: y, w: w, h: h, r: r, shape: boxes[i].shape, fill: boxes[i].fill.substring(1), multiMark: boxes[i].multiMark, q_id: boxes[i].q_id, q_option: boxes[i].q_option, _token: token}          
        });
```

-and finally the rout is the following

```
Route::post('/createform/{form}/update', ['as' => 'updateFormcoords', 'uses' =>'FormController@updateFormcoords']);
```

All of this is working pretty good but what I would really want is to create all of the field with a $request->all(), so I won't need to write down field by field of the DB, in other words this is what I am trying to do:

```
   public function updateFormcoords(Request $data, Form $form)
    {
        if ($data->ajax()){
            $formcoord=new Formcoord;
            $formcoord->create($data->all());
            $form->formcoords()->save($formcoord); 
        }
    }
```

but then a got the following error

> "SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'form_id' doesn't have a
>   default value (SQL: insert into `formcoords` (`field_name`, `x`, `y`,
>   `w`, `h`, `r`, `shape`, `fill`, `q_id`, `q_option`, `updated_at`,
>   `created_at`) values (asdf, 0.08479087452471483, 0.018527667984189724,
>   0.09125475285171103, 0.06027667984189724, 0, 10, 91e57b, 0, 0, 2017-02-23 16:13:00, 2017-02-23 16:13:00))"

I don't understand because I thought Laravel eloquent was supposed to fill the form_id field automatically when saving the row in the parent DB table variable (in the code line “$form->formcoords()->save($formcoord)”.
I appreciate a lot any help

Best regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't do create, create will attempt to create the row, but you haven't associated it with any form yet.

Do:

```
 $formcoord=new Formcoord($data->all());
 $form->formcoords()->save($formcoord);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works now perfect, I'm just getting started with laravel, really appreciate your help